# MaxResults with ISets in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, pagination, icriteria

I have an ICriteria which because of some aliasing and eager fetching I'm doing returns duplicate results - no problem, add them to a HashedSet and that'll remove the duplicates.

My issue is that I'm paginating the results to 10 results per page with the SetMaxResults method, this means that I return 10 results from my query.  Once imported into the ISet this becomes two or three...

Is there a way I can use and ICriteria mechanism to run a query which returns 10 results after the duplicates have been removed?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your query to remove the Cartesian Products (duplicates).

Comment: my understanding was that this was the standard way of dealing with NHibernate's eager loading duplicates?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do a query to fetch your related collections after the first query returns your paged entities

Comment: Are you querying on an association or child collection?